# Linq select a record based on child table data

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Trying to select orders based on their current status which is stored in a another table. Keep getting all orders instead of orders filtered by current status. When status is not empty, the query should filter based on the latest status of the order which I think should be status in descending order of date of record taking the first status.

```
private IQueryable<order_tbl> CreateQuery(string status, int? orderId, DateTime? orderDate) {
    var query = from o in context.order_tbl select o;

    if (orderId.HasValue) query = query.Where(w => w.id.Equals(orderId.Value));

    if (orderDate.HasValue) query = query.Where(w => w.OrderDate.Equals(orderDate.Value));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status)) {
        query = (from q in query
                from s in q.order_status
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.DateStatusUpdated)
                .Take(1)
                .Where(w => w.Status.Equals(status))
                select q);
    }

    return query;
}
```

There are more fields in the tables which I omitted for brevity.

order_tbl

```
id    date    customerId
1    2/1/2018      6
2    2/3/2018      5
3    2/6/2018      3
```

order_status

```
id    orderId    DateStatusUpdated   status
1        1         2/1/2018           open
2        1         2/2/2018           filled
3        2         2/3/2018           open
4        2         2/4/2018           filled
5        3         2/6/2018           open
```

When searching only on 'open', the query will return orders 1,2,3 instead of just order 3. What is wrong with the query on the status?

Comment: You are doing a cross-join from `query` to `status`. That means you get the pairs of each combination of one `q` and one `s`. If there exists any `s` with matching status, you will get every `q` matched to that one `s`, which you then narrow down to every `q`. Note that you don't narrow that `s` down to matching `orderId`. You need to `join` `q` to `s` or use a `where` on the cross-join matching the `q` to the `s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer pointed me in the right direction, [LINQ Query - Only get Order and MAX Date from Child Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267721/linq-query-only-get-order-and-max-date-from-child-collection?rq=1)

Modified my query to the below.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status)) {
{
    query = query
            .SelectMany(s => s.order_status
                              .OrderByDescending(o => o.DateStatusUpdated)
                              .Take(1)
                       )
            .Where(w => w.Status.Equals(status))
            .Select(s => s.order_tbl);
}
```